# Get If (condition), then (assign value), else (assign other value) statement in Linear Programming

Tags: excel, linear-programming, excel-solver

I'm looking for a linear programming equation that satisfied the conditions;

Given that all variables here are binary variables

`if A+B = 2; then C = 1; else C = 0`

Also,

`if A+B+D = 3; then E = 1; else E = 0`

How would one phrase this and satisfy these conditions as well as linearity conditions?

I've tried

`A + B - 2 <= M(1-y) and 1 - C <= My`

for the first constraint but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first equation, you can use:

```
C + 1 >= A + B
2C <= A + B
```

If there is a natural sense (max/min) for `C` in the problem, one of those is sufficient.

Similarly for the second:

```
E + 2 >= A + B + D
3E <= A + B + D
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Did you derive this from a formula? If yes, could you show me? Thanks.

Comment: For binary variables, one way to systematically translate is to translate the statements into a propositional CNF and then to translate the clauses into inequalities. Works well for the given examples.

Comment: These type of things are relatively common and you might want to pick up a textbook on Linear Programming that covers Integer Programming, or something that covers IP/MIP fundamentals...  When in doubt, set up a small truth table and check 'em.